# Sending Email prompts Error: 535 Authentication Failed

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am trying to send an email using CodeIgniter. When I try to send email, I get this error:

```
Failed to authenticate password. Error: 535 Authentication Failed for no-reply@sample.com
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
```

And I am working with this code:

```
$config = Array(
        'protocol'    => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host'   => 'smtpout.secureserver.net',
        'smtp_port'   => '465',
        'smtp_user'.  => 'no-reply@sample.com',
        'smtp_pass'   => '0p9o8i7u',
        'smtp_crypto' => 'ssl',
        'mailtype'    => 'html',
        'charset'     => 'iso-8859-1',
        'crlf'        => "\r\n"
);

$this->load->library('email', $config);

$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->from('no-reply@sample.com', 'SYSTEM ROBOT');
$this->email->to('recipient@outlook.com');

$this->email->subject('Sample Subject');
$this->email->message('HTML Content here');

if($this->email->send()){
    return true;
} else {
    return show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
}
```

My project is currently hosted by GoDaddy, as well as the email that I am using to send email (for this example is the no-reply@sample.com).

I based the SMTP settings from GoDaddy's website: https://ph.godaddy.com/help/mail-server-addresses-and-ports-for-business-email-24071

Password that I use is also correct because I try to login the email account using **RoundCube**.

How to fix the error that I am encountering?

Answer (score 0):

If your code above is your real one then try to change this parts with your actual account.

```html
'smtp_user'.  => 'no-reply@sample.com',
'smtp_pass'   => '0p9o8i7u',
```

because likely this **no-reply@sample.com** is not you real account

Comment: Yes, of course. I only stated sample in this post. But with my **actual** code, I am using the **correct** username and password.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue. I did not use what GoDaddy is suggesting in their [SMTP settings](https://ph.godaddy.com/help/mail-server-addresses-and-ports-for-business-email-24071):

```
'smtp_host'   => 'smtpout.secureserver.net'
```

First, go to your **Web Mail** page (something like: webmail.yourcpanel.com) and login the email account you will use to send email.

Then go to **Configure Mail Client** under **Other Webmail Features**. You will see the SSL/TLS settings for that email account. In my case, the SMTP host is different from what GoDaddy is suggesting:

```
'smtp_host'   => 'mail.sample.com'
```

After that, emails are now sending from my web application.